# Finding identical rows in subgroups with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My table has two IDs. I'd like, for each value of the 1st ID, to find whether two rows with different value of the 2nd ID are identical (excluding the column of the 2nd ID..).
A table very similar (but much much smaller) then mine is:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(id   = rep(LETTERS, each=10),
                 var1 = rnorm(260),
                 var2 = rnorm(260))


DT[, id2 := sample(c("A","B"), 10, T), by=id] # I need this to simulate different 
                                              # distribution of the id2 values, for
                                              # each id value, like in my real table

setkey(DT, id, id2)

DT$var1[1] <- DT$var1[2] # this simulates redundances
DT$var2[1] <- DT$var2[2] # inside same id and id2

DT$var1[8] <- DT$var1[2] # this simulates two rows with different id2
DT$var2[8] <- DT$var2[2] # and same var1 and var2. I'm after such rows!

> head(DT, 10)
    id           var1           var2 id2
 1:  A  0.11641260243  0.52202152686   A
 2:  A  0.11641260243  0.52202152686   A
 3:  A -0.46631312530  1.16263285108   A
 4:  A -0.01301484819  0.44273945065   A
 5:  A  1.84623329221 -0.09284888054   B
 6:  A -1.29139503119 -1.90194818212   B
 7:  A  0.96073555968 -0.49326620160   B
 8:  A  0.11641260243  0.52202152686   B
 9:  A  0.86254993530 -0.21280899589   B
10:  A  1.41142798959  1.13666002123   B
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
res <- DT[, {a=unique(.SD)[,-3,with=F]   # Removes redundances like in row 1 and 2
                                         # and then removes id2 column.
             !identical(a, unique(a))},  # Looks for identical rows
          by=id]                         # (in var1 and var2 only!)

> head(res, 3)
   id    V1
1:  A  TRUE
2:  B FALSE
3:  C FALSE
```

Everything seems to work, but with my real table (almost 80M rows and 4,5M of `unique(DT$id)`) my code takes 2,1 hours.

Has anybody got some tips to speed up the code above? Am I eventually not following the best practices needed to benefit from the `data.table` capabilities? Thanks anyone in advance!

EDIT:

some timings to compare my code with @Arun 's:

```
DT <- data.table(id   = rep(LETTERS,each=10000),
                 var1 = rnorm(260000),
                 var2 = rnorm(260000))

DT[, id2 := sample(c("A","B"), 10000, T), by=id] # I need this to simulate different 

setkey(DT)

> system.time(unique(DT)[, any(duplicated(.SD)), by = id, .SDcols = c("var1", "var2")])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.48    0.00    0.49 
> system.time(DT[, {a=unique(.SD)[,-3,with=F]   
+                   any(duplicated(a))}, 
+    by=id])
   user  system elapsed 
   1.09    0.00    1.10
```

I think I got what I wanted!

Comment: iiuc, if `id2` has both `A` and `B` then you want to check if there are duplicated `c(var1, var2)` rows? Is that so? Can there by more than 1 duplicate, ex: rows 3 and 4 are identical to one another? And if so, is the value still TRUE for any amount of duplicates?

Comment: In your example, two rows with "same" value of ID2 are identical, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun hi, I'm looking for row(s) with `id2=="A"` equal(s) to any other row(s) with `id2=="B"` for each value of `id`. Obviously excluding the column id2, so `c(var1, var2)` to be matched.

In my example two rows, 1st and 2nd, with same id2 are identical. Yes I want that to simulate my real table, but such case doesn't count in the result, in fact I use `unique(.SD)` and then I remove the 3rd column, which is `id2`.

Comment: Michele, it is confusing because you say everything seems to work, but the output is wrong for what you explain, isn't it? I mean if `id2 == A`'s `var1` and `var2` are identical to any of `id2 == B`'s `var1` and `var2`, then it should be a TRUE. But you've a TRUE when both id2 == A... for 1st and 2nd rows.. could you please explain if I've got something wrong?

Comment: @Arun Ok, sure. I want identical rows for **different** values of `id2`. If there are identical rows with the same `id2` they are discarded by `unique(.SD)`. Then removing the third column (`id2`) from `a` I can look for duplicates regardless the `id2` value. Is that clear? For `id=="A"` I get `TRUE` because row 1 and row 8 are identical (and have **different** `id2`). I set that using `DT$var1[8] <- DT$var1[2]` (waiting for your answer in the other question :-) ).

Comment: Thanks, I'm about to edit with some timing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
unique(setkey(DT))[, any(duplicated(.SD)), by=id, .SDcols = c("var1", "var2")]
```

It takes about 140 seconds to set the key on my "slow" machine. And the actual grouping is still going on... :)

---

This is the huge data I'm testing on:

```
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(id = rep(1:4500000, each=10), 
                 var1 = sample(1000, 45000000, replace=TRUE), 
                 var2 = sample(1000, 45000000, replace=TRUE))
DT[, id2 := sample(c("A","B"), 10, TRUE), by=id]
```

Comment: I think that `unique` in `data.table` works against the keys only. In fact I get one row per each combination of `id` and `id2`. As a result, I get `FALSE` for all the levels of `id`. Replacing with `unique.data.frame` gives the correct result, but it would be more likely to run out of memory with big data in this way, wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, there's no `key` set for `DT` in this answer.

Comment: Michele, you've huge data. Either you should worry about memory or about time. But not both, I think :).

Comment: got it! What about increase the speed with 16 GB of RAM :))). Anyway, besides memory issues which can be avoided for this question, changing to `unique.data.frame` is **very** slow (as expected) and setting the key to all the 4 columns you code is more than twice faster. see edit in a minute.

Comment: @Michele, yes that's what I am testing right now. I'd just add `setkey(DT)` before this line and I suspect that's the fastest you can get...

Comment: hmm, this seems quite slow (maybe faster than yours but still slow). I'll try to find another solution if possible. I suggest you "unmark" the answer so that you get other ideas in the meanwhile.